# How Mule Round Robin Flow Control Works

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi i am working with Mule Any Point Studio and just want to know how Mule Round Robin Flow Control works internally , on what basis its decide to call the particular Processor Chain block.

I just want to understand the working , because as i know the concept of Round Robin it allocates the time slices to the processes and then it will run based on that. But how it works here.

I have already gone through the Mule Website [Link](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RoundRobin) but not much information i got , in fact i got confused please briefly describe if possible.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to know is in the [implementation](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/RoundRobin.java) and in the [test](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/test/java/org/mule/routing/RoundRobinTestCase.java).

It will just route to the next (or the first when exausted) route every time a new event arrives.